# How to refactor factory classes using lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

A common use case is to have some kind of factory classes defined:

```
public abstract class IFactory {
    public abstract Object getObject(String input);
}
```

An implementation factory should probably provide the object based on the `input`.

For example:

```
public class FactoryImpl {
    private static instance = null;

    public IFactory instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            return new IFactory() {
                @Override
                public Object getObject(String input) {
                    return new Object(); //based on input data in real 
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is cumbersome, so I'd like to refactor the code using `lambda` expressions.
But what is the preferred way?

I could imagine the following two alternatives:

```
public class FactoryImpl {
    public IFactory instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            return (data) -> new Object(); //explicit using new operator
        }
    }
}

public class FactoryImpl {
    public IFactory instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            IFactory factory = Object::new;
            return (data) -> factory.getObject(); //using method reference
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an approach that should be preferred (eg for readablility or conventions)?

Comment: An abstract class can't be instantiated with a lambda even if it has a single abstract method. Then it's obvious that the second alternative won't compile as you can't instantiate an interface. Thus `data -> new Object()` is the way to go. But I suggest you to read some documentation before asking questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your life unnecessary complicated.

If you have an `interface` like

```
public interface IFactory {
    Object getObject(String input);
}
```

you may implement it as

```
public class NameIsIrrelevant {
    public IFactory instance() {
        return input -> new Object();
    }
}
```

without thinking about the singleton pattern. While it is not guaranteed, the implementation *does* return a singleton implementation here as it always does for non-capturing lambdas.

This is not an iron-hard guaranty but on the other hand, there is no harm if the returned instances are not singletons…

---

This has nothing to do with the question whether you will use lambda expressions or method references.

If the type your factory ought to construct has a constructor which accepts the factory’s input as a parameter value, you may implement the factory as

```
public class NameIsIrrelevant {
    public IFactory instance() {
        return TheType::new;
    }
}
```

but that’s only a minor optimization or rather a stylistic choice; it does not change in any way how the factory works. If there is no such constructor, there is no point in trying to use a method reference anyway.